# Find the average co-ordinates for each classifier in a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, coordinates

I want to write a function that takes two inputs:

`points` is a list of co-ordinate points and;

`classiification` is a list of 1s or 0s of n-by-m length, where n is the number of values in `points`, and m is is the number of classifications.

The function would return the average of the co-ordinates assigned to each classification. In the example there are 2 classifications, and each co-ordinate in `points` can only be assigned to one classification (labelled with a 1, all others labelled a 0).

Example below:

```
points = np.array([[1,1], [2,4], [4,6], [5,6], [6,6]])
classification = np.array([[1, 0],[1, 0],[0, 1],[0, 1],[0, 1]])
```

```
my_func(points, classification) #--> np.array([[1.5 , 2.5],
                                #              [5. , 6. ]])
```

So the first point, (1,1) has been assigned to the first classifier (1,0) and the third point (4,6) has been assigned to the second classifier (0,1).

What is the best way to approach this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since dictionaries are the easiest way to operate on the data involving mapping. I've used a dictionary to solve your question.

```
points = np.array([[1,1], [2,4], [4,6], [5,6], [6,6]])
classification = np.array([[1, 0],[1, 0],[0, 1],[0, 1],[0, 1]])
```

I'm converting the list of lists to list of tuples in the below step as lists cannot act as keys for dictionaries due to their mutable nature.

```
classification =[tuple(i) for i in classification]
dic={}
for i,j in zip(classification,points):
    if i not in dic.keys():
        dic[i]=[list(j)]
    else:
        dic[i].append(list(j))
[[sum(elem)/len(elem) for elem in zip(*j)] for i,j in dic.items()]
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. create two arrays, `result` and `count`, both with the number of classifications as their size, initialize each value to `[0, 0]` for result and `0` for count.
2. take the next point and classification until there are none left
3. use `classification.index(1)` to find the index for the `result` and `count` array
4. add the values of the point to the corresponding `result` and increment the corresponding `count`
5. repeat step 2
6. divide each value in result by it's corresponding `count` value
7. return `result`

I'll leave it up to you to write the code for it.

Comment: Thank you. I’ll give this a shot and post back.